# How to correctly install MySQL Ruby Gem

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, bundler

I am trying to install the Ruby GEM for MySQL. I am pretty new to Ruby.

I have RVM and Bundler installed. Should I install the gem via Bundler or RVM?

What would be the actual command to do so correctly?

Comment: you should accept the answer (the tick on the left)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you are inside the directory of your application, and after creating your gemset as Srdjan mentioned, you have two choices. Either run:

```
gem install mysql
```

or add this line to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'mysql'
```

Once you have added that line to your Gemfile, run:

```
bundle install
```

EDIT

You have to configure your database through the `database.yml` file for each one of your environments (development, staging and production). That should look like this:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  database: name_of_your_database
  encoding: utf8
  host: localhost
  username: root (replace with the actual username)
  password: root (replace with the actual password)
```

Once you have that set up, you can add [migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html) to add tables to your database. If this is a legacy database, you might need to generate some models from it. In order to do this you can use the [legacy_database](https://github.com/alexrothenberg/legacy_data) gem.

You don't have to handle the connection to the database yourself, Rails will do it for you. To access your tables and query them you can use the [ActiveRecord](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) methods.

For instance, suppose you have a table called `users` and you need to find a user by id, you could do this:

```
user = User.find(id)
```

Read the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) to get running on querying using Active Record.

Comment: @Amokrane I used your option #1 and I get the gem to show up in my environment, but when I try to do this require 'mysql' in my Ruby code, I still get an error that it doesn't recognize mysql.  Any idea why?

Comment: @GeekedOut What are you exactly trying to do? Once the gem is installed you are not supposed to require it yourself, it's already done under the hood for you! I suppose you need to use it as an adapter inside your database.yml file! adapter: mysql something like that...

Comment: @Amokrane I am trying to require the MySQL gem in a controller so I can connect to the database. I try to do something like this: require 'mysql' -- or should I just do that via the database.yml file?  If so, how do I explicitly connect/query the db from the server code?  - Thanks!

Comment: @Amokrane It helps.  I get this error now: uninitialized constant HomeController::User - any idea why?  Do I still need to do something like this in the code: require 'mysql'

Comment: Do you have a table named 'users' in your database? Do you have a model User (which is defined by a class that derives from ActiveRecord::Base)? (Oh and forget about the require 'mysql' anyway :)).

Comment: @Amokrane I have a table like that.  But not the model.  Would the User model class be like a POJO in Java OOP for example?  Where should it live?

Comment: It's exactly like a POJO in Java (Although you don't have to manually write the attributes and the accessors for each field of the table, actually it's way more easier). And ActiveRecord could be seen as JPA. The models live inside the app/models directory. You can generate them using the following command: rails generate model User.

Answer (score 4):

Since you have RVM installed, create a gemset for your application. This'll isolate the gems for that app only and not affect the rest of the system.

```
rvm gemset create appname && rvm gemset use appname
```

Once you've done that, install gems without sudo, either manually or through bundler, ensuring the isolation.

Comment: I would vote you up, but it requires me to have 15 reputation points lol :)

Comment: Thanks, I did your commands.  Now how can I get the MySQL GEM into this gemset?  - Thanks!

Comment: @GeekedOut, once you have the gemset created, any gem install done through the command line or bundler will automatically add it to the gemset. As for how to do it, follow @Amokrane's answer below.

Answer (score 2):

To get MySQL installed and running you'll need a few things:

- The development headers installed for MySQL and Ruby
- A working `mysql_config` or `mysql_config5` binary
- `gem 'mysql'` listed in your `Gemfile`

Once you've got all these in place, it should come together quite cleanly using the routine:

```
bundle install
```

Comment: Thanks! What do you mean "development headers installed for MySQL and Ruby?" - What changes does that entail?   Other than that, I already have MySQL installed and running.

Comment: Some systems come with only the binary files required to run both, but do not include the header files, something necessary to compile extensions and drivers. On some distributions this is provided in a separate, optional `-devel` package.